# How to solve for the moment generating function for this problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Find the moment generating function of the discrete random variable X that has the probability distribution

f(x) = 2($\frac13)^x$ for x=1,2,3...

$$
M_x(t) = \sum_x e^{tx}\cdot 2(\frac13)^x
$$

$$
M_x(t) = 2\sum_xe^t\cdot e^x \cdot (\frac13)^x
$$

$$
M_x(t) = 2e^t \sum_x (e/3)^x
$$

I have no clue where to go from here. Can I get some help? I think it has to do with a geometric series

Comment: You're right to suspect a geometric series, but you've made an error: $e^{xt}\neq e^t\cdot e^x$ (does $2^{6}=2^2\cdot 2^3$?)

Comment: Okay so then my last two steps are incorrect

Comment: Okay I understand. I still get the last line but $e^{tx} = (e^x)^t$. But I'm confused where to go from there. I get its a geometric series but what does that do to the $M_x(t)$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $e^{tx}\neq e^{t}e^x$ in general. However, since 
$$e^{tx}\cdot 2\left(\frac13\right)^x=2\left(\frac{e^t}3\right)^x,$$
the sum giving $M_X$ can be computed like a geometric series.